# JAXB umarshalling NumberFormatException Not a number: 2.444 at com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseInt(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:132)

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

While unmarhsalling I am getting the below error

**java.lang.NumberFormatException
Not a number: 2.444 at com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseInt(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:132)**

**Using JAXB unmarshalling method I am unmarshalling an XML which looks like below**

```
<ProductID itemName="Pen" itemNumber="123-123" effectiveDate="2017-04-10">
  <Amount value="2.444" UOM="g"/>
</ProductID>
```

**in this I am trying to retrieve the value attribute in Amount tag .

While generating JAXB classes from xsd as "value" name conflicts with value  xs:String so I annotated it with below code**

```
<xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
        <jxb:property name="valueAttribute"/>
    </xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
```

So in my JAXB Class ,I can see beans in the below format

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "value" })
public static class Amount {
    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "value")
    protected Byte valueAttribute;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "UOM")
    protected String uom;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the value property.
     * 
     * @return possible object is {@link String }
     * 
     */
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the value property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            allowed object is {@link String }
     * 
     */
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the valueAttribute property.
     * 
     * @return possible object is {@link Byte }
     * 
     */
    public Byte getValueAttribute() {
        return valueAttribute;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the valueAttribute property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            allowed object is {@link Byte }
     * 
     */
    public void setValueAttribute(Byte value) {
        System.out.println("insde set value attribute"+value.byteValue());
        this.valueAttribute = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the uom property.
     * 
     * @return possible object is {@link String }
     * 
     */
```

Any one please help me to resolve this issue
Thanks in advance....

Comment: Check the data type defined in the XSD, `2.444` is a `decimal` but it's trying to parse as an `integer`

Comment: In XSD it is defined as xs:String . So JAXB classes are generated according to that . JAXB will unmarshall the XML directly through code when we  input XML .I didn't find any use of XSD after generating JAXB classes . Could you please  give me some idea to resolve this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the `value` attribute of `Amount` is `Byte`/`integer` in your xsd. If it is, it should be a `double` or `float`.

Change your declaration  `protected Byte valueAttribute;` to `protected double valueAttribute` or `protected float valueAttribute`;

and in your xsd, it should appear like:

```
<xs:attribute type="xs:double" name="value">
     <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
                <jxb:property name="valueAttribute"/>
          </xs:appinfo>
     </xs:annotation>
</xs:attribute>
```

Comment: I changed the type of getValueAttribute() return type to Float . It is working now . Thank you so much for your answer .  instead of using getValue() in my businness logic now I am using getValueAttribute().